# Record real IP address on using phoenix in the nginx upstream

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an upstreaming phoenix app, like that:

```
upstream my_app {
    server localhost:3001;
}

server {
    root /var/www/my_app/priv/static;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_app;
    }
}
```

I want to track real IP address, but I don't know how to do it via standard phoenix `conn.remote_ip` because its always return `127.0.0.1` (because `nginx` proxies this query to phoenix). How can I fetch real ip address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `x-forwarded-for` header designed especially for that!

```
# nginx
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

# phoenix
conn.get_req_header(conn, "x-forwarded-for")
```