# IP address of a user always 127.0.0.1

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Here's how I'm recording an ip address of a user:

```
{a, b, c, d} = conn.remote_ip
ip_addr = "#{a}.#{b}.#{c}.#{d}"
```

It's always 127.0.0.1, even on a remote server when I'm testing it in production. What's going on?

The correct headers are passed from nginx.

Comment: I would guess that you're using some load balancer or proxy, such as haproxy or nginx, and client IP is not properly forwarded.

Comment: Can you share your prod config.

Comment: @IvanYurov I have the proper headers set up in nginx config

Comment: Can you post your nginx config along with your question?

Comment: even with the correct settings in your reverse proxy, the only thing it will do is set a header like `X-Original-Host` to the actual IP from which the request came from. You can use a plug to overwrite the remote_ip field in the conn that simply gets this header and then writes it into the conn struct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Record real IP address on using phoenix in the nginx upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198323/record-real-ip-address-on-using-phoenix-in-the-nginx-upstream)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using a reverse proxy or load balancer before your application (as you probably should).

This system will establish connectios (on behalf of the client) to your application. As it is running on the same host as your application, you will always see 127.0.0.1 as the remote host.

A reverse proxy will usually insert an [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) HTTP header. By extracting the value from that header, you should be able to retrieve the host that you are interested in.

Please note that there might be multiple proxies on the way between the client and your application. In such a case the header might look like

```
X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2
```

In this case you'll need some logic to determine which is the relevant host for you.